# Angular show datepicker icons inside an input box

Tags: angular, typescript

I have input field and datepicker. Issue is its showing in a row but i need to show icon inside a input box.

My code

```
        <div class="mb-2" style=" float: left;" class="example-full-width" class="col-6">
          <tc-form-label class="mb-1">Start Date</tc-form-label>
          <div style="display: inline-flex;align-items: baseline; box-sizing: border-box;"> <input
              placeholder="Select Date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [readonly]="formCallId == '3'"
              formControlName="startDate"
              style="border-radius: 20px; background-color: #EBEBEB; height: 2.75rem; border: 2px solid #EBEBEB; outline:none;    text-indent: 1rem; font-size: 1rem; width: 8rem;">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Its look like this right now

[image]

I need to show this icon inside to input boxes

Answer (score 0):

You could move the icon and shift them relatively using CSS. Alternatively you could wrap the icon and the text box in a span and have the span with the round-radius in css.

E.g.

Your second div is perfect for this. Just move your styling to it rather than the input text box.

```
<div class="mb-2" style=" float: left;" class="example-full-width" class="col-6">
      <tc-form-label class="mb-1">Start Date</tc-form-label>
      <div style="display: inline-flex;align-items: baseline; box-sizing: border-box;border-radius: 20px; background-color: #EBEBEB; height: 2.75rem; border: 2px solid #EBEBEB; "> <input
          placeholder="Select Date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [readonly]="formCallId == '3'"
          formControlName="startDate"
          style=" outline:none;    text-indent: 1rem; font-size: 1rem; width: 8rem;">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
```